# Getting Error While Uploading Deepracer Custom Files

Tags: amazon-web-services

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32qn5.png)

Can any one help to fix this PLEASE

As I gave a command

root@Anish:/home/somesh/git/deepracer-for-cloud# dr-upload-custom-files
Is give that error ☝️

After changing the access key and secret key . It showing same error
I have also given the permisson IAM full accessS3

Comment: please don't include text as screenshots.  Copy and paste the text itself into a text block which you can delineate with lines containing only  triple-backtick ```